# Bing Maps equivalent for gesturehandling as in Google Maps

Tags: scroll, touch, bing-maps, panning

I'm using Bing Maps V8 and would like to have the functionality as in the gesturehandling property of Google Maps, where the map does not scroll with page scroll in a touch device, and indicates for a two finger scroll.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different map options you can use to disable things like scrolling, panning, zooming, but no option to change panning so that it uses two finger touch instead of one. This is by design to create a consistent experience across all platforms and apps that use Bing Maps. I can't count the number of times the "gesture" handling support has frustrated me when go from one app to another, both using google maps, but requiring different gestures to move the map.

That said, if you want to mimic this behavior, it is possible to do so but disabling panning of the map, unless two fingers are pressed on the page. You would just need to add an event for detecting a two finger press on the map div element, and then change the disablePanning map option accordingly.

Comment: I recommend using Azure Maps. Here is a sample that reproduces this behavior: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html?sample=Limit%20Scroll%20Wheel%20Zoom

You may also find this useful: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html?sample=Limit%20Map%20to%20Two%20Finger%20Panning

Comment: Here are the current, non US Gov cloud links: https://samples.azuremaps.com/index.html?sample=Limit%20Scroll%20Wheel%20Zoom

https://samples.azuremaps.com/index.html?sample=limit-map-to-two-finger-panning

Comment: Seems like this site is updated quite frequently.  Here are the latest URLs: - https://samples.azuremaps.com/?sample=limit-scroll-wheel-zoom - https://samples.azuremaps.com/?sample=limit-map-to-two-finger-panning - https://samples.azuremaps.com/

Comment: Sadly, when I left the team, the person who took over the sample site got overly excited about making site their own and ended up breaking all the URLs. It drives me nuts that they haven't fixed this 3 years later.